# For-loop + echo changes the needed format of my output

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, echo

so I'm writing a script to take specific parts of the output from a pre-existing script and send them via HTTP POST.

I need to send them in the following format: `blade.$hostname.cpu=$cpuvalue` and `blade.$hostname.mem=$memvalue` with `$hostname, $cpuvalue and $memvalue` being the output from the previously mentioned script.

I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in {10..11}
do
  name=`./getdata.v7 $1 $2 | grep LINX"$n" | cut -c1-6`
  cpu=`./getdata.v7 $1 $2 | grep LINX"$n"_processor-usage | cut -c24-25`
  mem=`./getdata.v7 $1 $2 | grep LINX"$n"_memory-usage | cut -c21-22`
  echo -e "blade.$name.cpu=$cpu\nblade.$name.mem=$mem"
done
```

But when I run the script i get this result:

> blade.LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10.cpu=2
>
> blade.LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10
>   LINX10.mem=96

Could anyone help me as to what I need to change to only get the LINX10 part once instead of 36 times (yes i counted them)?

There is probably a very silly mistake in what I wrote but I'm new to bash and no matter what i try I can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you show some example output from the first script?

Comment: `{10..11}` is probably easier written `10 11`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would only call `./getdata.v7` once:

```
data=$(./getdata.v7 "$1" "$2")
```

Then I would manually write out `10 11` because you really don't need the brace expansion for two words:

```
for n in 10 11; do
```

Then, I would only want the first match from grep, because it seems to be matching `LINX$n` on multiple lines.

```
name=$(fgrep "LINX$n" <<< "$data" | head -n 1 | cut -c1-6)
cpu=$(fgrep "LINX${n}_processor-usage" <<< "$data" | head -n 1 | cut -c24-25)
mem=$(fgrep "LINX${n}_memory-usage" <<< "$data" | head -n 1 | cut -c21-22)
```

Note I'm using `fgrep` instead of `grep` because the matches don't need to be regular expressions. The entire pipeline could probably be rewritten in a single `awk` statement, but we don't need to go there.

Then, I would use `printf` instead of `echo` for readability:

```
printf 'blade.%s.cpu=%s\n' "$name" "$cpu"
printf 'blade.%s.mem=%s\n' "$name" "$mem"
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the quick response, the reason I have the brace expansion is because I'll have the script running for 90 Servers once it's done, I just used the output for 10 to 11 in the question because I didn't want to post 3 pages of repetitive output. ;)
Yeah I found out this morning after some extensive testing that the output of the previous script is a metric with 18 parameters per Server and since grep counts LINX100 as a match for LINX10 it came back with 36 matches :P
Doing it your way also makes it a TON faster, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for n in {10..11}
do
  name=`./getdata.v7 $1 $2 | grep -o LINX"$n"`
  cpu=`./getdata.v7 $1 $2 | grep LINX"$n"_processor-usage | cut -c24-25`
  mem=`./getdata.v7 $1 $2 | grep LINX"$n"_memory-usage | cut -c21-22`
  echo -e "blade.$name.cpu=$cpu\nblade.$name.mem=$mem"
done
```

grep manual:

> **-o, --only-matching**
>
> ```
>   Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
> ```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick response, the -o definitely helps, yet I'm not sure that alone would have solved the problem as the expression LINX10 appears on 36 different lines in the output from the getdata.v7 script. Thanks for the answer though, always usefull to learn new parameters for commands :)